# EntityManager is null when injected in WildFly 10 EJB

Tags: hibernate, jboss, persistence, entitymanager, wildfly-10

I have been working on moving our application from JBoss AS 6 to Wildfly 10. The main problem I have been stuck on is that the EntityManager does not get injected into the EJB. I have been researching this for a while and trying everything I find but nothing helps.

I don't have a simple application to recreate the problem yet but here are some details and snippets of code.

We are deploying using a SAR file. This is a Spring framework application. Our second level cache is turned off for now. That's another problem I need to tackle.

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
        version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="IpsDb" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/HarmonyServerDS</jta-data-source>
    <jar-file>../harmonyserver-model.jar</jar-file>
    <properties>
      <!-- pessimistic lock timeout in milliseconds (Integer or String), this is a hint used by Hibernate but requires support by your underlying database. -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="15000"/>
      <!-- query timeout in milliseconds (Integer or String), this is a hint used by Hibernate but requires support by your underlying database --> 
      <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="15000"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform" />
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Beginning of the datasource from standalone-full.xml:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/HarmonyServerDS" pool-name="HarmonyServerDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" spy="false" use-ccm="true" connectable="false">
```

From the EJB class (These are the important parts but not all of the code from the class):

```
@Stateless
@Clustered
public class DataModificationBean implements DataModificationLocal {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="IpsDb")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityMgrFactory;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="IpsDb")
    private EntityManager entityMgr;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @InterruptOnTransactionTimeout(value=true)
    public DataModificationResponse handleModification(DataModification mod, ModificationHandler handler, AdaptationContext adaptation, boolean bulk_lock)
    {
        try {
            // Handler's data update monitor for delta changes. 
            DataUpdateMonitor updateMonitor = null;

            // Pre-process the request and gather up the dataContext for processing.
            logger.info("DataModificationBean EntityMgr=" + (entityMgr == null ? "null" : entityMgr.toString()));
            logger.info("DataModificationBean EntityMgrFactory=" + (entityMgrFactory == null ? "null" : entityMgrFactory.toString()));
            handler.preProcess(this, entityMgr);
...
```

The logging at the bottom of that snippet shows that the entityMgr and entityMgrFactory are null.

Is there something else I'm missing? Or anything else I could show that would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had to change JNDI bean names from what I guess was an old format to the new format. I had changed some of these but not the one for this bean. The bean wasn't found from the context so a new one was created in the code. We have this code in there only for test cases but I didn't notice that was what it was doing. Now that I fixed the JNDI name, the bean is found and the EntityMgr gets injected.